# How to scroll to the bottom when a new message appears in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a realtime chat application in which people get joined to a single group and chat to each other. It is working fine but whenever there is a new message, the message gets hidden behind the box where I am displaying the chats. Not only that it is an even bigger problem if lots and lots of chats are appearing because the user have to scroll again to the bottom and it gets very irritating. So what I want to implement is if the user has scrolled to bottom then if a new message appears then scroll automatically to the bottom and if he is not at the bottom then nothing will happen. This is because if the user is reading a message which has gone up the I don't want the page to go to the bottom again and again. Here is some code that reproduces the problem.

```js
let i = 0;
setInterval(function addMessage() {
  container.innerHTML += `<div class='message'> message ${i++}</div>`;
}, 200)
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

As you can see in this example, the new message is getting hid and is not showing the newer messages this is what I have to overcome.

I would love if somebody helps me out. And thanks for reading my query!

Comment: Consider adding minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, so we could help on more specific issue. And in case if you're using javascript, you can read current scroll value of the DOM, and invoke a scrollToBottom function if it met certain value http://sourcetricks.com/2010/07/javascript-scroll-to-bottom-of-page.html.

Comment: @HilalArsa done i have added the code you asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

```js
let i = 0;
setInterval(function addMessage() {
  container.innerHTML += `<div class='message'> message ${i++}</div>`;
  if(//the user has scrolled to bottom
  container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop < container.offsetHeight * 2) {
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
  } // else if he is not at the bottom then nothing.
}, 200)
```

```css
#container{
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: One more thing sorry but it seems you are missing something from the question.